# "TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji" while coding Reaction Roles for a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror, emoji

I have been following the Worn Off Keys Discord.JS guide to get to know discord.js better, even though I understand JS fairly well. I got to a problem though when coding the reaction roles. I cloned the code for a special file from the WOK Discord JS repository. I usually clone the files and then adapt them to my liking, adding and removing some parts. But this time when I ran the code to test the basic clone out, I got an error saying `TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji` I couldn't find any place where I could fix this, as it worked in the tutorial video with the exact same code.

Here is my code for the special reaction roles file:

```js
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')

module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelId = '870818745109585920'

    const getEmoji = (emojiName) => client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)

    const emojis = {
        red_circle: 'CrackShot / Sniper',
        orange_circle: 'Scrambler / Shotgun',
        yellow_circle: 'Whipper / P90',
        green_circle: 'RPEGG / RPG',
        blue_circle: 'Free Ranger / Semi-Auto',
        purple_circle: 'EGG-K / AK-47',
        white_circle: 'TriHard / AUG',
        black_circle: 'Cluck-9mm / Pistol'
    }

    const reactions = []

    let emojiText = '**GUN ROLES**\n\n'
    for (const key in emojis) {
        const emoji = getEmoji(key)
        reactions.push(emoji)

        const role = emojis[key]
        emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
    }

    firstMessage(client, channelId, emojiText, reactions)

    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
        if (user.id === '869698265698947102') {
            return
        }
        const emoji = reaction._emoji.name

        const { guild } = reaction.message

        const roleName = emojis[emoji]
        if(!roleName) {
            return
        }

        const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName)
        const member = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id)

        if (add) {
            member.roles.add(role)
        } else {
            member.roles.remove(role)
        }
    }

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
        }
    })

    client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, false)
        }
    })
}
```

The `first-message` file that you see there is:

```js
const addReactions = (message, reactions) => {
    message.react(reactions[0])
    reactions.shift()
    if (reactions.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => addReactions(message, reactions), 750)
    }
}

module.exports = async (client, id, text, reactions = []) => {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id)

    channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
        if (messages.size === 0) {
            channel.send(text).then((message) => {
                addReactions(message, reactions)
            })
        } else {
            for (const message of messages) {
                message[1].edit(text)
                addReactions(message[1], reactions)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And all I added from those files to the main `index.js` file is `const roleClaim = require('./role-claim')` and later inside the `client.on(ready)`etc. part I added     `roleClaim(client)` to run the bot code. Any suggestions? Sorry for the giant amounts of text. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have emojis with names like `red_circle`, `orange_circle`, etc. [`client.emojis.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=emojis) only contains custom emojis the bot has access to.

So, when you use `getEmoji()` to get the emoji you'll receive undefined. You don't check the `emoji` value inside that function and just add it to an array (`reactions.push(emoji)`). Later, when you try to add the reaction (`addReactions()`), you try to react with `undefined`. As it's not an emoji, you receive the error.

A solution would be to use emojis available, and you could also simplify the for loop

```js
let emojis = {
  '': 'CrackShot / Sniper',
  '': 'Scrambler / Shotgun',
  '': 'Whipper / P90',
  '': 'RPEGG / RPG',
  '': 'Free Ranger / Semi-Auto',
  '': 'EGG-K / AK-47',
};
let emojiText = '**GUN ROLES**\n\n';
let reactions = [];

Object.entries(emojis).forEach(([emoji, role]) => {
  reactions.push(emoji);
  emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`;
});

console.log(emojiText)
console.log(reactions)
```

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
  let channelId = '870818745109585920';
  let emojis = {
    '': 'CrackShot / Sniper',
    '': 'Scrambler / Shotgun',
    '': 'Whipper / P90',
    '': 'RPEGG / RPG',
    '': 'Free Ranger / Semi-Auto',
    '': 'EGG-K / AK-47',
  };

  let reactions = [];
  let emojiText = '**GUN ROLES**\n\n';
  Object.entries(emojis).forEach(([emoji, role]) => {
    reactions.push(emoji);
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`;
  });

  firstMessage(client, channelId, emojiText, reactions);

  function handleReaction(reaction, user, add) {
    if (user.id === '869698265698947102') return;

    let emoji = reaction._emoji.name;
    let { guild } = reaction.message;
    let roleName = emojis[emoji];
    
    if (!roleName) return;

    let role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName);
    let member = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id);
    // TODO: check if role and member exist
    if (add) {
      member.roles.add(role);
    } else {
      member.roles.remove(role);
    }
  }

  client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
      handleReaction(reaction, user, true);
    }
  });

  client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
      handleReaction(reaction, user, false);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your attentiveness and help! So I replaced the red_circle emojis with the real emojis in a string, tried that out and it still didn't work, but then I simplified the for loop AND IT WORKED! Thank you so much for your time and effort!